# How do I ensure the correct precedence in Emacs highlighting keywords?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm trying to write a simple major mode for a lisp dialect. Here's my mode:

```
(defconst example-font-lock-keywords
  (list
   `(";.*" . font-lock-comment-face)
   `(,(regexp-opt '("function" "macro") 'symbols) . font-lock-builtin-face)
   `("\"[^\"]+?\"" . font-lock-string-face))
  "Highlighting for Example mode.")

(defvar example-mode-syntax-table
  (make-syntax-table))

(define-derived-mode example-mode lisp-mode "Example"
  "Major mode for editing Example lisp code."
  :syntax-table example-mode-syntax-table
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults) '(example-font-lock-keywords)))
```

Here's my sample program:

```
; Highlighting tests.
; This is a comment despite "quotes"

(function foo () "bar")
```

Here's the result I'm seeing:

[image: emacs screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? Why does the string regexp 'win' against the comment regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs highlights a buffer in two phases. The first is the *syntactic* phase, which is based on information found in the syntax table, which typically highlights strings and comments. The second is the *keyword* phase.

In your case, the default syntax table sets up double quotes to mean string. The effect is that before your keywords are executed, the strings are already highlighted. By default, a keyword is only applied when there is no highlighting in the matched content, which is the reason why your comment keyword only works on lines without strings. (See the `OVERRIDE` flag in the help text of `font-lock-keywords` for details on overriding.)

The best solution for you is to update the syntax table so that ; means "comment start", and then drop the comment and string rules from your set of keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Try `("\"[^\"]+?\"" 0 font-lock-string-face keep t)`.

Or reverse the order of the two entries (for `font-lock-comment-face` and `font-lock-string-face`).

See the Elisp manual, node `Search-based Fontification` -- look for `OVERRIDE` for an explanation of `keep`.